# Convert string in Shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a following varaible:

```
tags = {
    environment  = "development",
    provider     = "ServiceOne",
    ansible_role = "nfs-role",
    comment      = "mysql"
}
```

In my pipeline i need to convert it to the following:

```
tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -hcl-var "tags={environment=\"development\", provider=\"ServiceOne\", ansible_role=\"nfs-rolep\",comment= \"mysql\"}"
```

I have tried with **SED** and **AWK** but couldn't get any result?

This is where i am standing now:

```
#!/bin/bash

#[[ -z "$2" ]] && echo "==> Usage: ./transform_tfe_vars.sh <<INPUT_FILE>> <<OUTPUT_FILE>>" && exit 1;

vars_file=${1}
#output_file=${2}
tmp_file=".todelete.tmp"

cmd "$vars_file" | grep -v '^#' | awk '!/^$/' > "$tmp_file"


while read -r p; do

    a=$(echo "$p" | awk '{print $1}')
    b=$(echo "$p" | awk '{print $3}')
    echo "tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -shcl-var \"$a=\\""$b""\""

done <$tmp_file
```

Comment: yes, i have added the input.. it should look something like above

Comment: You turned it into a different question that my answer which you accepted doesn't entirely work for. I put this question back as it was when I posted my answer - please ask a new, followup question if you need more help.

Comment: I have created a new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68923925/convert-different-type-of-strings-with-awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shell read loop is always the wrong approach for manipulating text, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). The guys who invented shell also invented awk for shell to call to manipulate text.

It looks like this might be what you're trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

(( $# == 2 )) || { echo "==> Usage: ${0##*/} <<INPUT_FILE>> <<OUTPUT_FILE>>"; exit 1; }

vars_file="$1"
output_file="$2"

awk '
    BEGIN {
        ORS = ""
        print "tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -hcl-var \""
    }
    NF && !/^#/ {
        gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"")
        gsub(/"/,"\\\\&")
        print
    }
    END {
        print "\"\n"
    }
' "$vars_file" > "$output_file"
```