# Convert different type Of strings with AWK

Tags: shell, awk

I have the following Variables in my config file:

```
tags = {
    environment  = "development",
    provider     = "ServiceOne",
    ansible_role = "nfs-role",
    comment      = "mysql"
}
line                       = "b01"
my_lb_ports                = "[53, 80, 443, 389, 636, 3268, 3269, 6443]"
dns_servers                = "[\"8.8.8.8\", \"9.9.9.9\"]"
```

For my Pipeline i need to convert it to the following:

```
tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -hcl-var "tags={environment=\"development\", provider=\"ServiceOne\", ansible_role=\"nfs-rolep\",comment= \"mysql\"}"

tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -hcl-var "line=\"b01\""

tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -hcl-var "my_lb_ports=[\"53\", \"80\", \"443\", \"389\", \"636\", \"3268\", \"3269\", \"6443\"]"

tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -hcl-var "dns_servers=[\"8.8.8.8\", \"9.9.9.9\"]"
```

Following script was created with support from @Ed Morton, but it still not identifies all patterns:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

(( $# == 2 )) || { echo "==> Usage: ./${0##*/} <<INPUT_FILE>> <<OUTPUT_FILE>>"; exit 1; }

vars_file="$1"
output_file="$2"


awk '
    BEGIN {
        ORS = ""
        print "tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -hcl-var \""
    }
    NF && !/^#/ {
        gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"")
        gsub(/"/,"\\\\&")
        print
    }
    END {
        print "\"\n"
    }
' "$vars_file" > "$output_file"

awk -F'=' '{ gsub( /\x22/ ,"\x5c\\&", $2 ); gsub( / / ,"", $1 ); gsub( / / ,"", $2 );  print "tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -hcl-var \x22" $1 "=" $2 "\x22"}'  "$vars_file" >> "$output_file"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good start, you'll need to figure out how to adjust the `"`s in the lines for output:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

(( $# == 2 )) || { echo "==> Usage: ./${0##*/} <<INPUT_FILE>> <<OUTPUT_FILE>>"; exit 1; }

vars_file="$1"
output_file="$2"

awk '
    BEGIN {
        ORS = ""
        beg = "tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -hcl-var \""
        end = "\"\n"
    }
    /^[[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]*=/ {
        gotBlockBeg = 1
        gotBlockEnd = ( $NF == "{" ? 0 : 1 )
    }
    gotBlockBeg {
        block = block $0
        if ( $NF == "}" ) {
            gotBlockEnd = 1
        }
    }
    gotBlockEnd {
        gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"",block)
        gsub(/"/,"\\\\&",block)
        print beg block end
        gotBlockBeg = gotBlockEnd = 0
        block = ""
    }
' "$vars_file" > "$output_file"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file foo
```

```
$ cat foo
tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -hcl-var "tags={environment=\"development\",provider=\"ServiceOne\",ansible_role=\"nfs-role\",comment=\"mysql\"}"
tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -hcl-var "line=\"b01\""
tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -hcl-var "my_lb_ports=\"[53,80,443,389,636,3268,3269,6443]\""
tfh pushvars -overwrite-all -dry-run false -hcl-var "dns_servers=\"[\\"8.8.8.8\\",\\"9.9.9.9\\"]\""
```

Add debugging `print` statements anywhere you don't understand what's happening in  the awk script or run it using the gawk debugger (`gawk -D ...`).